# Linq to Sql get today date only data from db

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

i am unable to get the data from db with date only comparison. In Db `InDateTime` datatype is `DateTime`

```
using (HatronEntities context = new HatronEntities())
{
     DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
     var AttendData = (from c in context.tbl_CoachMobAttendDetails
                       where c.CoachId == model.Id && c.InDateTime.Value.Date ==date
                       select c).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (HatronEntities context = new HatronEntities())
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime until = date.AddDays(1);
    var AttendData = (from c in context.tbl_CoachMobAttendDetails
                        where c.CoachId == model.Id && 
                        c.InDateTime.Value >= date &&
                        c.InDateTime.Value < until
                        select c).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You didn't say initially that it was Linq To Entity Framework - but you say Linq To SQL! Then:

```
using (HatronEntities context = new HatronEntities())
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
    var AttendData = (from c in context.tbl_CoachMobAttendDetails
                        where c.CoachId == model.Id && 
                        DbFunctions.TruncateTime( c.InDateTime ) == date
                        select c).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: EntityFunctions is deprecated now!

Comment: `EntityFunctions` is obsolete. For any new applications using versions of EF starting with 6.0, you should use the `DbFunctions` class

Comment: Yes you can use that if you will and if you are targeting EF6 and later. Bottomline EntityFunctions or DbFunctions, you need to use TruncateTime here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
c.InDateTime.Year == date.Year && c.InDateTime.Month == date.Month 
&& c.InDateTime.Day == date.Day
```

or like

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.InDateTime.Value.Date) == date.Date
```

Comment: error : The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @sandeepsingh:- Updated my answer. Please check!

Answer (score 0):

**Try [Like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499987/LINQ-query-to-compare-only-date-part-of-DateTime)**

```
c.InDateTime.Value.Date.Year == date.Year &&
c.InDateTime.Value.Date.Month == date.Month &&
c.InDateTime.Value.Date.Day == date.Day
```

Comment: error : The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx) method:

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.InDateTime.Value.Date) == date.Date
```